# TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi i have a column G2: G in googlesheet named 'Rank sheet' with storename like
`column G
 storeA
 storeB
 storeC
 storeA
 storeA
 storeD`

I want to create a function name 'remove' (google apps script) to delete row of duplicated names, but when i run it, gsheet say :"TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined." Can anyone can help me to fix it or help with your code. Thank so much
My code is:

```
function remove() {
  var range2 = rankSheet.getRange("G2:G");
  var values2 = range2.getValues();
  for (var n = 0; n < values2.length; n++) {
if(values2[n] == values2[n+1]) {      
  var outarray = []
  outarray.push(n+2)
  Logger.log(outarray)
  }
}
  for (var m = 0; m <= outarray.length - 1; m++) {
  rankSheet.deleteRow(outarray[m]);
  }
}
```

Comment: the first thing to do would be to move var outarray = [] above your for loop. instead of adding to it you are are setting it to a new blank array every time you go through the loop.

Comment: var range2 = rankSheet.getRange("G2:G"); --  where does rankSheet come from? it is not defined in your function. is it from a global variable? you need to let people know these kind of things when you're asking questions.

Answer (score -1):

That means that in your fourth line, you are trying to access a property called `length` from an object that doesn't exist.  So if you look at line 3, your `getValues()` call on `range2` is returning `null`

Also keep in mind `getValues()` returns a two-dimensional array
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

Try logging out `values2` after you assign it and see what it is ^^